# Проверка url

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

**Нужна функция по проверке url надо чтобы были условия**

отправляем - получаем

[name.ru](http://name.ru) - http://name.ru

http://name.ru - http://name.ru

https://name.ru - https://name.ru

[name.ru/](http://name.ru/) - http://name.ru

[www.name.ru](http://www.name.ru) - http://www.name.ru

http://www.name.ru - http://www.name.ru

http://www.name.ru/en/ - http://www.name.ru/en

С регуляркой не дружу, откровенно говоря. :( Ну хоть примерное что-то киньте.

p.s. Да гуглил, ничего толкового не нашёл :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = array('name.ru', 'http://name.ru', 'https://name.ru', 'name.ru/', 'www.name.ru', 'http://www.name.ru', 'http://www.name.ru/en/');

foreach($url as $get => $view)
{
    if(!preg_match("/(http|s:\/\/)/", $view))
    {
        $view = "http://" . $view;
    }

    $view = preg_replace("/(http|s)(.*?)\/$/", "$1$2", $view);

    echo $view . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное... то что надо...

Answer (score 0):

По возможности, я стараюсь избегать регулярок, поэтому, если вас устроит вариант без таковой, то можно сделать так:

```
$str = 'www.name.ru';
$arr = explode('://',$str);
if($arr[0] != 'http' && $arr[0] != 'https'){
    $str = 'http://'.$str; 
}
if(substr($str,-1) == '/'){
    $str = substr($str,0,- 1);
}
echo $str;
```

Comment: ссылка типа `name.ru/` не проканает!

Comment: Проканает )) Не предполагаю, а уверен на все сто.

Comment: Слеш в конце останется, а ТС'у нужно их срезать) добавить на крайняк `echo trim($str, '/')`

Comment: @Palmervan, а в этом смысле... Ну, и тут без регулярки можно обойтись.

    $str = 'name.ru/';
    $arr = explode('://',$str);
    if($arr[0] != 'http' && $arr[0] != 'https'){
        $str = 'http://'.$str; 
    }
    if(substr($str,-1) == '/'){
        $str = substr($str,0,- 1);
    }
    echo $str;

Comment: Можно не спорю)